# Semantic UI Sortable Table Exclude Column

Tags: semantic-ui, sortables

Semantic UI Sortable Table, are they any class/tag that I can exclude some column to be sortable.

Such as Action Button column which should be have sorting disabled.

[Semantic UI Tables](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/table.html)

Please advice, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the class **no-sort** class to the th

I looked at the javascript at

https://semantic-ui.com/javascript/library/tablesort.js

And saw the line

```
this.$sortCells = this.$thead.length > 0 ? this.$thead.find('th:not(.no-sort)') : this.$table.find('th:not(.no-sort)');
```

Comment: Thanks will try and come back to vote for helpful answer if it work.